# Are there any tools for drawing on the desktop (drawing over apps)?

Tags: xorg, desktop-apps

I am wondering if there is anything similar to [ink over apps](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ink-over-apps/com.ntkachov.penandpaper) for linux. i.e. , a program that allows me to draw over any other program given Xs architecture, it should be possible, but I looked for it and could not find it.

---

EDIT: I have two good suggestions by Roman Raguet: one in his answer, and one in the comments.

I'd like more suggestions, and, if possible, one that does not require a composite window manager

Comment: the perfect answer for 95% of people is probably Roman's.

Comment: now ... is there any way to do this on vanilla X ?

Comment: I am runnung ubuntu, but instead of running Unity (that my machine cannot handle) I run fluxbox.

My PC does not have much of a graphic card, but I'll test this xcompmgr

Comment: Tried all on Ubuntu 17.04, only Pylote worked for me.

Comment: I installed compiz. which one is button1? ?

Comment: @info-farmer Open up a terminal and type xev. Click on the box that will pop up, there's two events that can give away which "button" you're currently pressing, ButtonPress event and ButtonRelease.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### **EDIT**:

### Option 1  *(compiz composite manager)*

As far as I read about the **ink over apps** application... you can try with the ***"Annotate"*** plugin in compiz.

**1)** Intall the *compizconfig-settings-manager*, *compiz-plugins* and the *compiz-plugins-extra* packages running code below.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra
```

**2)** Open the compizconfig-settings-manager application.

[image]

**3)** Go to the **"Extras"** category and enable the **"Annotate"** plugin.

[image]

**4)** Click in the plugin to view and set the configuration.

[image]

5. configure the plugin according to your needs.. here you have an example.

[image]

You can launch whatever application, draw in it and use the shorcuts for the *gnome-screenshot* app like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> to take the screenshot of the windows you drew.

### Option 2  *(with any composite manager eg: xfce, compiz, xcompmgr etc)*

Another software to draw over the desktop is [Ardesia](https://code.google.com/p/ardesia/).

> Ardesia is the free digital sketchpad software that help you to make
> coloured free-hand annotations with digital ink everywhere, record
> them and share on the network. It is easy to use and impressively fast
> and reactive. You can draw upon the desktop or import an image and
> annotate it and redistribute your work to the world. Let's create
> quick sketch and artwork.

**1)** To install Ardesia, open a Terminal and type:

- `sudo apt-get install ardesia`

**2)** To open the app eg: Xubuntu.

Go to *Menu > Accessories > Ardesia Desktop Sketchpad*

[image]

**3)** You can draw over and app or your desktop and you can take screenshots with the Ardesia toolbar.

[image]

### Option 2.5

If you have a slow computer, you might want to try option 2 using lxde and xcompmgr (a lightweight composite manager)

To run lxde and xcompmgr,

**1)** Install both programs

```
sudo apt-get install lxde xcompmgr
```

**2)** follow the instructions at [How to start applications such as xcompmgr at start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78926/how-to-start-applications-such-as-xcompmgr-at-start-up) to get xcompmgr to start in lxde

This option works rather well, even on slow computers.

### Option 3  *(without composite manager)*

Another application to draw but without a composite manager is [Pylote](http://pascal.peter.free.fr/pylote-en.html).

> Pylote is a software making it possible to draw on the screen of the
> computer, like handling various instruments of geometry. It is a
> software multiplateforme, free (license GNU GPL), made in Python
> (computer programming language) and PyQt4 (or PySide) for the
> graphical interface.

To run Pylote you need first python (greater than or equal to 2.6) installed by default in Ubuntu, and python-qt4.

**1)** Open a Terminal window and type:

- `sudo apt-get install python-qt4`

**2)** Download the [pylote.tar.gz](http://pascal.peter.free.fr/wikiuploads/pylote.tar.gz) file. [(Pylote install GNU / Linux)](http://pascal.peter.free.fr/pylote-en.html#download)

**3)** uncompress the tar.gz file

- `tar xvzf /path/to/pylote.tar.gz`

**4)** Enter in the pylote folder and make sure the file **pylote.pyw** has execute perms.

- `cd /path/to/folder/pylote`
- `chmod 755 pylote.pyw`

**5)** Run the pylote app with double click in the **pylote.pyw** file

[image]

[image]

**6)** Take an screenshot after drawing over an app or your desktop. eg: scrot

- `sudo apt-get install scrot`

Then you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

- `scrot -s /path/to/your/screenshot.jpg`

with the -s option you can select the area to take the screenshot and save at .jpg.

Hope this will helpful.

Comment: this is very cool! Thanks.

I am keeping the question open for a while, to see if anyone has an idea that does not involve compiz (because my poor computer can't manage to run it), but, if no one does, I'll drop by later to mark this as accepted

Comment: @josinalo... You can try my third option "Pylote" without a composite manager.

Comment: well, in the end I managed to run xcompmgr on my PC. It worked rather well.

I Just added details on how I got it working on a "option 2.5"

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Technically, Pylote does not really draw over the desktop, but on automatically generated screenshots of the desktop. You can minimize the Pylote window to see the real windows and the real desktop behind.

Comment: not working in default Ubuntu 18.04, use `sudo apt-get install gromit-mpx` as explained below

Comment: What is Button1?

Comment: Very nice summary of options; thanks!  What I have not figured out is how to apply it to a window so that it becomes a part of that window, rather than the desktop.  This is so that I can project a single window in a jitsi videocon and annotate it.  If I annotate the desktop, the projection shows nothing.

Comment: Ubuntu-package search shows Option 2: __[Ardesia](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ardesia) was last available in Xenial__ (16.04) - discontinued, so `apt` wont work. May update your post and alternate install to `dpkg` from their [code.google archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ardesia/downloads) please!

Comment: Still works to this day in ubuntu 20.04 :)

Comment: @MaratZakirov and anyone that is trying to find what Button1 is. Open up a terminal and type `xev`. Click on the box that will pop up, there's two events that can give away which "button" you're currently pressing, `ButtonPress event` and `ButtonRelease`.

Answer (score 41):

You can use [gromit-mpx](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx). It allows screen annotating with line and textmarker tools of configurable color, varying them in thickness based on pressure (if you have a Wacom pen or similar). As requested, it does not require a compositing desktop manager, but will benefit if you have one.

**Usage under Debian / Ubuntu**

1. Install it:

   sudo apt-get install gromit-mpx
2. Start it with `gromit-mpx`.
3. Press the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key (or <kbd>F9</kbd> key) and start painting on the screen. This is Debian/Ubuntu specific, as per `man gromit-mpx`.
4. Press <kbd>Pause</kbd> again to stop painting on the desktop, using it again "like normal".

Alternatively, you can control the software from the command line (`gromit-mpx --toggle` to start/stop painting) or from a taskbar icon. The "Toggle Painting" menu item in the taskbar was the only one to not work for me, though.

[More details](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx#how-to-use-it) on how to use this software. Also, see [this video.](https://youtu.be/dXg5NM8qncU)

**User experience without compositing**

gromit-mpx works work with both compositing and non-compositing window managers, but in the latter case it can be slow / sluggish [[source](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx#potential-problems)].

I used it without compositing. Using and scrolling the original windows below the annotations was always fast for me. Painting with gromit-mpx itself was initially fast but then became very sluggish (= painting low-polygon lines). After clearing the screen (`gromit-mpx --clear`) or erasing enough pixels, painting became fast again. The issue seems connected to the amount of painted pixels (not the amount of line segments). If you only need it for circling some 4-5 things on the screen and adding a word or two, no problem, but after that you want to use it with a compositing window manager. (`xcompmgr` is a lightweight one. See "Option 2.5" in [@Roman Raguet's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/328584) on how to set it up.)

Comment: Working for me with Mint 17 xfce (with compositing turned on), whereas I couldn't get mouse drawing to work in ardesia (only text worked, and even that vanished after a few seconds).

Comment: Couldn't get Gromit work on Ubuntu 17.04. For any option, it says "unknown option". And I have no Pause key.

Comment: +1 for Gromit, it's the only solution on this page that worked on my Manjaro i3 + picom setup! o/

Answer (score 5):

You can use GNOME Shell extensions [Draw On You Screen](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1683/draw-on-you-screen/):

> Start drawing with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
> Then save your beautiful work by taking a screenshot.

[image]

### Features

- Basic shapes (rectangle, circle, ellipse, line, curve, polygon, polyline, text, image, free)
- Basic transformations (move, rotate, resize, stretch, mirror, inverse)
- Smooth stroke
- Draw over applications
- Keep drawings on desktop background with persistence (notes, children's art ...)
- Multi-monitor support
- Export to SVG

### Install

Install as any other *GNOME Shell extension*. For detailed instructions see the [README, Install](https://framagit.org/abakkk/DrawOnYourScreen#install) on author's *framagit* repo.

ℹ️ Note: GNOME Shell 41 and later are not supported (currently only 3.24 - 3.38)

Comment: You posted a link-only answer, so I added some details to improve.