# Libreoffice presentation - Highlight / draw during the talk

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, presentation

I have some slides on which I would like to highlight some aspects live during the talk. My slides will be able to be used as pdf also. (As I'm not using any Libreoffice special abilities.)

Is there a tool existing for Libreoffice or a pdf viewer that would enable me to do this. Or might Powerpoint be able to use my Libreoffice slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerpoint might be able to open them, if you save it as .pptx, but the formatting will be messed up. You could set a slightly translucent box to appear over the text (say if you click on it).

You could also try drawing over the desktop - see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328543/drawing-over-the-desktop).

Answer (score 2):

You also could use [Open-Sankoré](http://open-sankore.org/), or [OpenBoard](http://edu.ge.ch/sem/equipement/outils/openboard-logiciel-libre-denseignement-numerique-interactif-1223)