# clutter - Draw above Gnome Shell Desktop

Tags: gnome, xorg, clutter

I am aware of the question [Drawing over the desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328543/drawing-over-the-desktop) and I don't think this question is a duplicate.

I need a simple way to draw stuff above my Gnome Shell desktop with some scripting language. The preferred solution would be one which doesn't depend on installing a composite manager or making a transparent window.

It seems that Clutter can deal with multiple z levels, and extensions such as WindowOverlay Icons make me believe it IS possible to do draw above the Desktop.

Now, I've just installed libclutter-1.0-doc but I can't find good examples on how to do it. Besides trying to understand WindowOverlay Icons source code, is there any snippet or tutorial showing this specifit use of Clutter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is all, what you need: https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/

Comment: @A.B. This is a too broad direction.  I have the manual inside Devhelp (by installing libclutter-1.0-doc), but it isn't clear how to draw on a fullscreen undecorated canvas. So far, I've tried to create a ClutterStage and call set_fullscreen and set_paint_callback. This isn't working... I think the overview is not well written, and I don't understand the relation between Actors, Stages, Windows and Canvas. I don't have the time to read just the whole "bare" API and try to find what I need. What I really want is some background on the main concepts, just like Cairo did in its tutorial.