# How to reset compizconfig-settings-manager settings?

Tags: command-line, unity, compiz

So I have a really stupid problem: I followed this tutorial ([Drawing over the desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328543/drawing-over-the-desktop)) and accidentally mapped the "Initiate line" hotkey to mousebutton 1, which means that left clicks are no longer registered and all that happens instaed is that I draw a green coloured line on my desktop that stays until I reboot my pc. I was wondering if there was a way to fix this issue using only terminal, which is pretty much the only application I can use right now. The graphics interface of compizconfig-settings-manager is pretty much completely inaccessible now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the **CCSM** Main screen (click) **Preferences** -> (click) **Rest to defaults**.

After making changes you can save various configurations and use this same screen to restore to a working configuration.  This way if it becomes unusable again, you won't have to back all the way back to the defaults.  You can restore a previous configuration.

Many of the settings under CCSM can be found in the **Unity Tweak Tool**.  Install this to gain control over the corrupted settings:

```
$ sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

This command will get restore most of the defaults:

```
$ unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

You may have to run the command `unity` to load the new settings.

Comment: Here is the problem though: I can't click. Whenever I try to, it draws a line on my monitor instead. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Try: `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`.  Then run `unity`.