# Screen annotations for Ubuntu 18.04, for changing backgrounds and possible to draw circles and write text

Tags: 18.04, annotation

I know the detailed answer of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328543/drawing-over-the-desktop/328584#328584).

But I tried `compiz composite manager` and it didn't work. I had no possibility to get `ardesia` running with installing with the source because there's no package in 18.04. With `pylote` (it works!) I only can draw on screenshots and not on changing screens.

The best possibility is `gromit-mpx` but I need straight lines, circles, rectangles and text, too.

**Is there a newer possibility for drawing free hand, lines, circles, rectangles and text on changing backgrounds?**