# Tool for drawing rectangle on the screen over apps programmatically

Tags: command-line, xorg

I'm developing some automation software which take the part of current visible screen for further processing. For debug purposes I need to highlight which part of the screen is being processed right now.

Is there any standalone cli tool which will draw a hollow rectangle at the desired coordinates for specified amount of time in seconds?

It should be a solution which doesn't block any user input, e.g. mouse click or change window focus.

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328543/are-there-any-tools-for-drawing-on-the-desktop-drawing-over-apps) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369223/are-there-any-cli-tools-for-drawing-graphics-on-the-screen-during-an-x-session) answers but it's not what I'm looking for.